# Code block structure highlighting extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image]

Does anyone know an extension for Visual Studio Code that highlight code blocks as in the image ?

Answer (score 2):

It is built-in to vscode.  Enable the setting

```
Editor > Guides: Bracket Pairs
```